# Twilio.Api.dll version mismtach with nuget?

Tags: c#, twilio

In VS2013, I started a new console app and issued a nuget command to pull down the latest Twilio.API.dll (as per the nuget gallery website)

```
Install-Package Twilio -Version 3.6.27
```

And I get:

```
Adding 'RestSharp 105.0.1' to Twilio.
Successfully added 'RestSharp 105.0.1' to Twilio.
Adding 'Twilio 3.6.27' to Twilio.
Successfully added 'Twilio 3.6.27' to Twilio.
```

...

And I build the console.  This puts the dependent DLLs in my bin/Debug folder.  When I right-click on the actual Twilio.Api.dll file, and go to the Details tab, it says the product version is 3.4.1.0.

Any ideas on why there is this version mismatch?  Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

A 3.6.27 is the version of the Nuget package, which contains all the references as described above.

What you're looking at is the assembly version for Twilio.Api. that comes from the [SharedAssemblyInfo.cs](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio.Api/SharedAssemblyInfo.cs) which is hardcoded. You are right however when you think this should change as it should ideally match the package version.

To answer your question though, what is important here is that you downloaded the correct Nuget package, and with that all the up-to-date references, so your project should work without glitches.

Comment: Thank you (it was just a bit confusing)!

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. I'll see if we get the SharedAssemblyInfo to update with the Nuget package